# Map Array Of Objects Passed From Parent (prop.array.map)

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

Could do with some help on a react app. I am trying to map an array of objects that has been passed down form the parent but it comes up with the error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

I can JSON.stringify as below and I can map the same array if it is defined in same file. Just can't map as a prop sent from parent.

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to map an array as below in the child component sent from parent.

```
const tracks = [
  {
  id: 1,
  name: "Song 1",
  artist: "Artist 1",
  album: "Album 1"
  },
    {
  id: 2,
  name: "Song 2",
  artist: "Artist 2",
  album: "Album 2"
  },
];
```

```
const App = () => {
  
  const mockData = "Song 1";
  

  const mockData1 = [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "Song 1",
    artist: "Artist 1",
    album: "Album 1"
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    name: "Song 2",
    artist: "Artist 2",
    album: "Album 2"
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing
      </h1>
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBar />
      < div className="App-playlist">
          <SearchResults 
            mockData={mockData}
            mockData1={mockData1}
            appObject={{
              id: 1,
              name: "Song 1",
              album: "Album 1",
              artist: "Artist 1"
            }}
  
          
          />
          <Playlist />
          <>
          {mockData1.map((item) => (
           <div key={item.id}>
              <div>{item.name}</div>
              <div>{item.album}</div>
              <div>{item.artist}</div>
            </div>
          ))}
          </>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

export default App;

```
const SearchResults = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="SearchResults">
      <h2>Results</h2>
      <TrackList 
        mockData={props.mockData} 
        appObject={props.appObject}
        tracks={props.mockData1} 
           
        />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchResults;

const TrackList = (props) => {
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
          <Track              
            mockData={props.mockData} 
            appObject={props.appObject}                                
          />
          <p>
            {JSON.stringify(props.tracks)}  
          </p>
          {props.tracks.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <div>{item.name}</div>
              <div>{item.album}</div>
              <div>{item.artist}</div>
            </div>
          ))}

      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default TrackList;
```

props.tracks.map - causing issue

Comment: Can you share the code of the parent and the child (specially where you passed the prop and where you loop through it)

Comment: Trying to reply but can only find this comment area

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After reviewing the updated information and the code provided, I have identified the bug you are facing. The issue lies in the usage of the same component, TrackList, in two different components, PlayList.jsx and SearchResult.jsx in App.jsx

```
<SearchResults 
  mockData={mockData}
  mockData1={mockData1}          
  />
 <Playlist />
```

**In SearchResult.jsx**
In SearchResult.jsx, you correctly pass the props to the TrackList component as shown in the code snippet you provided.

```
<TrackList 
mockData={props.mockData} 
tracks={props.mockData1} 
/>
```

You are passing a props and getting it in TrackList component.

**In PlayList.jsx**
However, in PlayList.jsx, you are not passing any props to the TrackList component, and you simply call it like , which leads to undefined props being received in the TrackList component.

```
<TrackList />
```

**TrackList.jsx**
so, when TrackList.jsx component call, it get props on first render but not on second render that which result in showing `undefined props`

You code is perfectly code if we comment the PlayList.jsx file but i assume you need this file.Therefore, you may use conditional rendering

**Solution**
To fix this issue, you can use conditional rendering in PlayList.jsx to ensure that the TrackList component receives the necessary props. You can modify the code as follows:

```
<TrackList
        tracks={props.mockData1 || []}
        mockData={props.mockData || ""}
/>
```

Comment: This code gives me the error. I can .stringify tracks but not .map.
Works if tracks is defined in child file
Cheers

Comment: can you share your code? so i can help you better

Comment: How do I reply or add code. The only response area I can find is this comment section

Comment: just edit your post and add your code in your actual post

Comment: Should be edited now. A lot of the code is for testing props.tracks.map is causing issue

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-compiler-forked-mfd2gs
check this out, i tried to run your code

Comment: could you execute the following code snippet and inspect the output: console.log("props.tracks.map", props.tracks.map)? This will allow us to determine the exact content obtained from the props.tracks.map expression. I have verified that the provided code is functioning correctly within CodeSandbox, but reviewing the console output will help us gain further insight into the situation.

Comment: Where should i place console.log.  where the. stringify is?
I

Comment: const TrackList = (props) => {
console.log("props.tracks.map", props.tracks.map)
    return (
here before the return

Comment: have you checked codesandbox?

Comment: So my .map method is set up correctly but could be an issue somewhere else in project????

Comment: yes, most probably.

Comment: I have looked at codesandbox but never used this. Sorry I am new to all this. I think you are saying that it works is sandbox but not sure if that means it should work locallly

Comment: When i try and console log and inspect the page (console) at local host it just displays: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') because page is in error.

Comment: I think the sandbox example is mapping the array that is in the same file. I am getting the error when i try and map the array in the child as a prop (sent from parent):
prop.track.map

Comment: Full project https://github.com/richiehales/jamming

Comment: Full project https://github.com/richiehales/jamming

Any advice would be great. Just trying to pass an array down to grandchild (mockData1 to SearchResults then to TrackList). Can't map the array set in App.js in TrackList.js. Can with hard coded array if defined in same file as in the repo

Comment: Hello Richie,

I apologize for the delayed response. I was occupied with my university assignments. I have cloned your repository and reviewed the code. I have addressed the bugs and now understand why it was not functioning properly. I have also updated my response on the post. Kindly review it. Additionally, I would appreciate it if you could clone the other branch as well, as I have submitted a pull request for it.

Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Data` is coming from an api try to do this:

```
prop?.array?.map(item => {
  //...
})
```

And make sure that the `prop?.array` is an array not object or something else (because maybe the api returns an object...).

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the project repository.

You need to rename the `Tracklist` folder to `TrackList` and the files `Tracklist.css Tracklist.js` to `TrackList.css TrackList.js`

When you've done that, reload npm start and it should work. I checked everything is working.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at that. I changed the file names a while ago and doesn't sync up for some reason,